# Android application crushs when I use xml file as icon

Tags: android, xml

Здравствуйте, у меня есть floating action button. Когда хочу использовать xml файл, который получил из svg файлa, как значок , приложение закрывается, в логе напишет  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_add.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02004d .  Помогите узнать в чем проблема

Comment: Попробуйте clean проекта сделать.

Comment: сделал , но не помог

Comment: Покажите как выглядит ненаходимый файл

Comment: Также попробуйте использовать версии либ 23.3.0 вместо 24+

Answer (score 1):

Проблема был в андроидах 5-, для решение нужна в gradle - е добавить vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary, а в месте android:src = "@drawable/ic_add написать app:srcCompat = "@drawabel/ic_add"